# Notations in Banach Tarski paradox proof

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Banach-Tarski Paradox**: The unit ball $\mathbb{D}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is equi-decomposable to the union of two unit balls.

**First part of Proof**:

Let $\mathbb D^3$ be centered at the origin, and $D^3$ be some other unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\mathbb D^3 \cap D^3 = \varnothing$.

Let $\mathbb S^2 = \partial \mathbb D^3$.

By the Hausdorff Paradox, there exists a decomposition of $\mathbb S^2$ into four sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ such that $A$, $B$, $C$, and $B \cup C$ are congruent, and $D$ is countable.

For $r \in \mathbb R_{>0}$, define a function $r^{*}: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ as $r^{*}(\mathbf x ) = r \mathbf x$, and define the sets:

$$    \displaystyle W = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(A)$$
$$    \displaystyle X = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(B)$$
    $$\displaystyle Y = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(C)$$
    $$\displaystyle Z = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(D)$$

---

Can someone please explain what $\mathbb S^2 = \partial \mathbb D^3$ means. Is it just partially differentiating a $3$ dimensional unit ball?

Also, what does $r \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ mean? I have absolutely no idea!!

Comment: $\partial\mathbb{D}^3$ is the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^3$, that is $\overline{\mathbb{D}^3}\setminus\mathring{\mathbb{D}^3}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is simply $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Could you try explain the $\partial \mathbb D^3$ more please. I still don't understand.

Comment: $\mathbb D^3$  is a solid ball in $3$-space.  Its boundary $\partial \mathbb D^3$ the the surface of that ball, which is a sphere.  It is the bounding surface of the ball.

Comment: $R_{>0}$ , the set of positive reals, is also written $R^+$.

Comment: $\partial$ means "boundary," here. $\partial A$ means the boundary of $A$. There is no differentiating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$, one defines: $$\partial A:=\overline{A}\setminus\mathring{A}.$$ One can show that: $$\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}.$$
In your case, $\partial\mathbb{D}^3$ is indeed the $2$-dimensional unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Hello can you or someone else explain what these expressions come out to be as please? Like what does it mean for r to be in between 0 and 1? Im talking about the 4 big expressions on main post. W, X, Y, Z